# C# - Unity Internal Compiler Error: "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite" CS0518 - when using dynamic variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, return, monodevelop, internal-compiler-error

Using MonoDevelop 4.0.1 to code for Unity 4.5.2f1

The code below is part of the code that I am using, all the variables have been checked using `Debug.Log` and they all (individually) return the correct values.

When I refresh my script asset in Unity, I get the following error message:

> Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' is not defined or
>   imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' is not defined or
>   imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' is not defined or
>   imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' is not defined or
>   imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' is not defined or
>   imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported
>
> error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' is not defined or
>   imported

Here are the sections of my script (simplified) causing this error:

*Note: I cannot break my function up into multiple little functions. **My function must remain as is** I can edit the return statement as needed*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class myScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    private dynamic someVar;
    private float myFloat = 1.1f;
    private string myString = "string";
    private int myInt = 2;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        someVar = myFunction(myFloat, myString, myInt);
    }

    //First Function
    public dynamic myFunction(float myFloat, string myString, int myInt)
    {
        //Do something
        dynamic myOtherFunction(myFloat, myString, myInt);
        float myFloat = myOtherFunction.myFloat;
        string myString = myOtherFunction.myString;
        int myInt = myOtherFunction.myInt;
        //Do something
        return new {myFloat = myFloat, myString = myString, myInt = myInt};
    }

    //Second function
    public dynamic myOtherFunction(float myFloat, string myString, int myInt)
    {
        //Do something
        return new {myFloat = myFloat, myString = myString, myInt = myInt};
    }
}
```

I have not been able to figure out what the issue is, (yes, even with using Google, although some possible solutions came up, I tried them, they did not seem to resolve my issue).

I need to be able to return multiple variables to the `OnGUI()` function from another function. The method I am using `return new{varName = value, ...};` I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303772/is-it-possible-to-return-multiple-values-with-different-types). I cannot use Tuples as Unity 4 MonoDevelop does not support it (according to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/381993/does-unity-4-mono-support-tuples.html) post) where a user posted:

> No, Unity does not support Tuples. Maybe when Unity upgrades its Mono version to support features that came in .NET Framework 4.

Ultimately, I would like to implement the following code in the `OnGUI()` function:

```
myFloat = myFunction.myFloat;
myString = myFunction.myString;
myInt = myFunction.myInt
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, 
Thank you

Comment: When you simplify an example be careful not to go _too_ far. You're reusing parameter names as local variable names, and it buries the actual problem.

Comment: My apologies, I did over simplify it a little, thank you for understanding what I was doing though. You've been a tremendous help

Comment: I was getting this error in my unit test project while dynamically compiling C# script using CSharpCodeProvider. Adding reference to "System.Core.dll" to CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into the same problem you did with Tuples. `dynamic` was introduced in .Net Framework 4.0 and requires the dynamic language runtime (DLR), which isn't present in Unity's version of Mono.

That being said, given the context you have here your note stating "My function must remain as is I can edit the return statement as needed" shows you don't need your current setup at all. I *really* can't see why you can't use an object to hold the values (the names you used are making it very hard to come up with logical names for an example):

```
    public class MyFunctionResult
    {
        public readonly float MyFloat;
        public readonly string MyString;
        public readonly int MyInt;

        public MyFunctionResult(float myFloat, string myString, int myInt)
        {
            MyFloat = myFloat;
            MyString = myString;
            MyInt = myInt;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        float myFloat = 1;
        string myString = "";
        int myInt = 2;
        var finalResult = myFunction(myFloat, myString, myInt);
        Debug.Log(finalResult.MyFloat); //...
    }

    //First Function
    public MyFunctionResult myFunction(float myFloat, string myString, int myInt)
    {
        //Do something
        var myOtherFunctionResult = myOtherFunction(myFloat, myString, myInt);
        float myFloatResult = myOtherFunctionResult.MyFloat;
        string myStringResult = myOtherFunctionResult.MyString;
        int myIntResult = myOtherFunctionResult.MyInt;
        //Do something
        return new MyFunctionResult(myFloat, myString, myInt);
    }

    //Second function
    public MyFunctionResult myOtherFunction(float myFloat, string myString, int myInt)
    {
        //Do something
        return new MyFunctionResult(myFloat, myString, myInt);
    }
```

I tried *really* hard to come up with an even *marginally* valid reason and couldn't (but I'm wondering if your simplification is hiding a hidden problem). That being said, you can also use `out` parameters, but I'd definitely call it a misuse:

```
public dynamic myFunction(float myFloat, string myString, int myInt)
{
    //Do something

    float myFloat;
    string myString;
    int myInt;
    myOtherFunction(out myFloat,out myString,out myInt);
    ...
}
public void myOtherFunction(out float myFloat, out string myString, out int myInt)
{
    myFloat = someVal;
    myString = otherVal;
    myInt = thirdVal;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I wasn't aware dynamic had the same issues as Tuple. It took me a while to implement but the first section/answer you provided worked like a charm. Thanks again